# Cannot read property 'fileChangeEvent' of undefined In Angular2

Tags: node.js, angular

Getting this error while choosing  image  file

```
  import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UploadPhotoService {
  filesToUpload: Array<File>;

    constructor() {
        this.filesToUpload = [];
    }

    upload() {
        this.makeFileRequest("rest/api/upload", [], this.filesToUpload).then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
        }, (error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }

    fileChangeEvent(fileInput: any){
        this.filesToUpload = <Array<File>> fileInput.target.files;
    }

    makeFileRequest(url: string, params: Array<string>, files: Array<File>) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var formData: any = new FormData();
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i].name);
            }
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    if (xhr.status == 200) {
                      alert("Upload successful!");
                    } else {
                        reject(xhr.response);
                    }
                }
            }
            xhr.open("POST", url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+localStorage.getItem("token"));
            xhr.send(formData);
        });
    }
}



     <div class="field">
  <label>Upload Photo</label>
  <input type="file" (change)="uploadPhotoService.fileChangeEvent($event)" />
  <button type="button" (click)="uploadPhotoService.upload()" class="ui mini button">Upload</button>

  </div>
```

After choosing image file it showing the above error , Is there any other way to upload image file in angular2.. Please help on that too, and its giving  EXCEPTION: Error in ./AddAdvertComponent class AddAdvertComponent - inline template:30:2 caused by: Cannot read property 'fileChangeEvent' of undefined

```
 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'fileChangeEvent' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

throwing error

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'fileChangeEvent' of undefined

because  you are calling `fileChangeEvent` not correctly or your `uploadPhotoService` have not definer,  you have to call it like this

if the method is in the same class

```
 <input type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" />
```

or if your method is in some different class or in some service than make sure you initilize that service in the constructor like this

```
constructor(prive uploadPhotoService: UploadPhotoService) { }
```

than you are able to use like this

```
<input type="file" (change)="uploadPhotoService.fileChangeEvent($event)" />
```